# Trying to resize my Ubuntu partition (dual boot with Windows) but Gparted gives a scary warning because the unallocated space is to the left?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am currently dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted more space on the Ubuntu side so I used Windows disk management tool to shrink that partition and that left me with 100+ GB of unallocated space.

I then booted into a live Ubuntu USB, chose the "try Ubuntu" option, and fired up Gparted.

Here's what you see when you get there:

[screenshot of my partitions... sda2 = Windows, sda5 = Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AchWN.png)

When I go to resize sda5 it shows the unallocated space being to the left of sda5.

[Here's the resize window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSgQX.png)

Now, when I drag sda5 to the left to take up all of the unallocated space, I get a scary warning about moving a partition causing failure to boot.

[Scary warning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seU7I.png)

So should I actually be concerned here? I've backed up my important files regardless. I tried googling this issue/warning and most seem to say it's unlikely to be an issue or that the warning only really applies to older boot methods. Is there another method I should use to get the unallocated space over to the right of sda5?

Thanks,

Comment: Moving Windows partitions can give a problem with booting, I’ve seen that on here several times. I don’t think you have anything to worry about here though. Moving a partition to the left will take an appreciable amount of time, unlike when adding space to the right. If you do have problems they should be easily fixed by reinstalling grub from the live environment or using the boot repair tool. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you, @ponjar

Comment: As an update, it went off just fine... and it only took 20 mins to move all the data. SSDs are amazing.